# Best mobile framework to build an iPhone app for a non mobile-dev?

Tags: ios, mobile

I'm a php dev, and i want to port my web application first on the iPhone.

The application is like a job board. The simple mobile app will have to (with my web-app API) :

- Auth users
- Browse job offers through categories
- Filter/Search job categories
- Send / Read private messages

I never used Java / Objective-C that's why i want to know if you can recommand me a framework (or not) that could do the trick without the need for me to learn 3 months before starting to code the application.

Which direction should I take ?

Thanks

Comment: iPhone has support for web apps. Why do you need a native app?

Comment: That's a good question i can't answer. So it means that i can go for a web app ?

Comment: This link could help you: http://www.apple.com/webapps/whatarewebapps.html One downside could be, that you can not sell web apps. On the French side there is even a link how to make a web app: http://www.apple.com/fr/webapps/whatarewebapps.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want a native app so that you can deploy to the AppStore and make some cash?  ;)

You can create HTML apps and wrap them natively which would let you leverage your existing skills.  There's various ways to do this and there's even some tools that will help you with the native wrapper. but for starters take a look at PhoneGap:

http://phonegap.com/